# Find the constant $c$ that makes $f$ continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

where:

$f(x)= x^2-c^2 $ if $ x<4$

$f(x)= cx+20  $ if $  x>=4$

Studying for my midterm:

So continuous only means that the two lines line up.

So:

$4^2-c^2=4c+20$

$4^2-20=c^2+4c$

$-4=c^2+4c$

$0=c^2+4c+4$

$0=(c+2)^2$

Now I know the answer is $c=-2$ but I have no idea how to get that from where I am in the equation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(c+2)$ times $(c+2)$ is zero **if and only if** either $(c+2)$ or $(c+2)$ is already zero.

Comment: Interesting, I never though of it that way, so we can just eliminate one of the $(c+2)$?

Comment: A tiny technicality: It should say $x^2-c^2$ if $x\le 4$, $cx+20$ if $x\gt 4$ (or $x^2-c^2$ if $x\lt 4$, $cx+20$ if $x\ge 4$). If we don't do that, the function will not be defined at $4$, so not continuous.

Comment: Ah, you're correct, I wrote it wrong.